# Нужна ли запятая после слова "также"? Правильно ли составлено предложение?

Tags: пунктуация

Также благодаря данному сайту можно прочесть про туристические поездки и найти отзывы гостей.

Comment: Будет легче ответить на этот вопрос, если Вы покажете это предложение в контексте, чтобы было ясно, к чему относится это "также".

Answer (score 3):

**Желательно использовать более ясные и лаконичные формулировки** с необходимым объемом полезной информации (принцип инфостиля):

Также на сайте можно ознакомиться с информацией  о туристических поездках и найти отзывы о работе турфирм.

Answer (score 0):

Предложение составлено верно в случае, если "прочесть про..." можно на подразумеваемом *другом* сайте (напр. благодаря ссылкам с данного); если  прочесть "можно" на том же сайте, о котором говорится (в добавление к ранее сказанному - о чём там можно прочесть), то правильнее сказать прямо:

> Ещё на данном сайте можно прочесть про туристические поездки и найти
>   отзывы гостей.

О запятых для исходного предложения - в случае подразумеваемого *другого* источника для "прочтения". Они не нужны (факультативны: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_56) в случае, если "также" относится только к "благодаря данному сайту", т. е. перед этим напр. говорилось, что благодаря тому же сайту возможно что-то первое. Если же "также" относится к "можно прочесть" (напр. перед этим можно было что-то другое, а это - только благодаря...), то требуется обособление уточняющего оборота "благодаря данному сайту" двумя запятыми.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1